# Putting and removing background color on click from button

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have problem with this code because it works. Well, partially. My idea is to change background color of button on which user has clicked but data-line attributes increments only once and by that changing background color only once. (it enters in else and changes data-line value from 0 to 1 but my idea is to increment its value further and then by concluding whether value is odd or even to remove or add bg-danger class). All buttons (all with trashCan class) initially have data-line attribute with value zero and neutral background color. What is wrong with this code?

```
$(".trashCan").click(function(){
        let trashCan = $(this);
        let trash = parseInt(trashCan.data('line'))+1;
        trashCan.attr('data-line',trash);
        if(trash%2==0){
          trashCan.removeClass("bg-danger");
        }
        else {
          trashCan.addClass("bg-danger");
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're accessing the `data-line` attribute with a mix of `attr()` and `data()`. The former reads from the DOM, while the latter reads from jQuery's internal cache. If you *get the value* with one of them you need to also *set the value* using the same method.

In the example below I've amended the logic to use `data()` only, which is the preferred choice where possible. If you absolutely have to update the DOM, then you would use `attr()` instead.

```js
$(".trashCan").click(function() {
  let trashCan = $(this);
  let trash = parseInt(trashCan.data('line')) + 1;
  trashCan.data('line', trash);
  
  if (trash % 2 == 0) {
    trashCan.removeClass("bg-danger");
  } else {
    trashCan.addClass("bg-danger");
  }
});
```

```css
.trashCan {
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border: 0;
}   

.trashCan.bg-danger {
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #FFF
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="trashCan" data-line="0">Trash</button>
```

However, it's worth noting that this logic is not necessary. It seems that your goal is simply to toggle the class on successive clicks, in which case just use `toggleClass()` and remove the `data` attribute entirely:

```js
$(".trashCan").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('bg-danger');
});
```

```css
.trashCan {
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border: 0;
}   

.trashCan.bg-danger {
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #FFF
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="trashCan">Trash</button>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help